# Could not build module 'AVFoundation'

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I've suddenly run into an issue when trying to build and run my app - I need to use AVFoundation and suddenly it's telling me the below message

Could not build module 'AVFoundation'

This comes a long with some other issues such as:
/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/Headers/MIDIDriver.h:390:83: Expected ')'

Which I find odd...

If I remove the import it of course builds and runs just fine.

I have tried several things i.e. adding it to Link Binary with Libraries, clearing derived data, cleaning the project etc etc with no luck.

I'm at a loss with this so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm running Xcode 9 and using CocoaPods - I'm also embedding some swift into my objective C code - something new to me, so could it be related to that perhaps?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think you may have edited that MIDIDriver.h file. Can you share the contents of that file around line 390?

Comment: @DaveWeston Thank you for the comment - I think I've found that it was caused simply by a preprocessor macro which I find a little strange. Once I have further evidence this is exactly what it was I will update the question.

Comment: Yeah, I've done exactly this in the past. I'm not sure why Xcode doesn't make it harder to accidentally modify system header files like that.